# How do I clean up the right-click context menu in Windows explorer?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-explorer, cleanup, context-menu

Sometimes applications plug into the context menu that I get on right-click on files and folders in Windows Explorer. After some time this menu gets really messy and I just want to clean it up.

Can you tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to edit your registry, it's easiest do do this for the context menu of directories:

- Run regedit
- Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`
- Remove the keys that correspond to the unwanted commands

Each filetype (file extension) has its own additional commands which you can find under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\.EXT`

If you want to remove a specific menu entry, it might be easier to just search for the context menu string in the registry.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to disable context menu addons.